# Validar si encuentra archivo adjunto VBA macro gmail

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

Tengo esta macro que envía varios correos al tiempo con diferentes adjuntos a X cantidad de correos previamente especificados.

Siempre los correos deben llevar un adjunto (es la razón de ser del correo), estoy intentando que cuando no encuentre el adjunto me muestre un error y salte automáticamente a enviar el otro correo, pero es el momento que no he encontrado la manera de hacerlo.

```vb
Public impresiones As Integer
Sub SendMail_Gmail2()
  Dim myrange As Range
  Dim contador As Integer
  Set myrange = Worksheets("Hoja1").Range("A:A")
  contador = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myrange)
  contador = 4
  For i = 2 To contador
    Dim Email As CDO.Message
    Set Email = New CDO.Message
    correo = ""
    passwd = "12345678"
    destino1 = Range("D" & i)
    destino2 = Range("E" & i)
    destino3 = Range("F" & i)
    destino4 = Range("G" & i)
    destino5 = Range("H" & i)
    destino6 = Range("I" & i)
    cliente = Range("B" & i)
    mensaje = "TITULO"
    cuerpo = "CONTENIDO"
    archivo = Range("K" & i)
    Email.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
    Email.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = 2
    With Email.Configuration.Fields
      .Item("...") = CLng(465)
      .Item("...") = Abs(1)
      .Item("...") = 30
      .Item("...") = correo
      .Item("...") = passwd
      .Item("...") = True
    End With
    With Email
      .To = destino1 & ", " & destino2 & ", " & destino3 & ", " & destino4 & ", " & destino5 & ", " & destino6
      .From = correo
      .Subject = mensaje
      .TextBody = cuerpo
      .AddAttachment archivo
      .Configuration.Fields.Update
      On Error Resume Next
      'If .Attachments.Item(Index) Is Nothing Then
      'MsgBox "no hay adjunto para: " & cliente
      'End If
      .Send
    End With
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
      MsgBox "El mail se envió con éxito a: " & cliente, vbInformation, "Mensaje Administrador"
      impresiones = impresiones + 1
    Else
      MsgBox "Se produjo el siguiente error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error nro " & Err.Number
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox "Se han enviado " & impresiones & " E-Mails correctamente"
  impresiones = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo únicamente envías un correo con varios destinatarios podrías crear un bucle que envíe de uno en uno los mensajes y en cada uno haga la comprobación

```
    If .Attachments.Item(Index) Is Nothing Then
      'MsgBox "no hay adjunto para: " & cliente
      'End If
```

porque por ahora con que un destino tenga adjunto ya no entraría en esta condición

Comment: El código ya incluye un For..Next